# CLI select default printer for xrdp-connected users according to user's IP

Tags: networking, xfce, xrdp

A few users connect to the server via XRDP. I need to write a script (on login to MATE) to assign a default printer (via `lpoptions -d`) for each user but depending on the IP address from which the user is connected to server.

To do this, I need to determine from which IP address each user is connecting. But so far I have not found a way to determine IP addresses of connected users. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://serverfault.com/questions/361565/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-desktop-client-and-how-can-i-trigger-a

Comment: No. This is "way to determine the IP address of a remote desktop client using PowerShell". I used linux and need determine IPs via bash. :)

Comment: Does `sudo netstat -at | grep localhost:3389` give you something useful, assuming you are listening on the default port?

Comment: netstat shows all connections at once without usernames. I need to run the script in the user environment of each user (after login to XFCE), and determine the source-ip of the current user. If I can find out the address of the current user, I can assign the correct printer to him.

Comment: The information I need can be seen in the /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log, right after login (via grep "created session". But I do not understand how I can catch these lines in a situation of simultaneous login of several users.

Comment: I found a solution.
Need to find a process:
"PROC=`ps aux | grep $USER | grep xrdp | grep Xorg | awk '{print $2}'`"
Now you can find user's IP:

USERIP=`cat /var/log/xrdp.log | grep $PROC | cut -d ":" -f 7 | cut -d " " -f1 | grep 192.168`
Solved.